# How to analyse stock market and find best company?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I am asking this for Academic purpose. and would appreciate your help here and if there is any reference that can support your answers

Here is the scenario

There are 4 companies in the stock market A, B, C, and D

I can watch these 4 companies stock for 4 weeks before make a decision which stocks are going to be the highest.

[image]

by the end of the 4 weeks period I have to analyse stock data and find a company that is most likely to be highest stock after 9 weeks.

is there a rule ( i know it is not guranteed) but if there is any rule that can help in making this decision?

I remember someone said to look for the stock that is going up

**Edit :**

Numbers in these tables are stock prices.

The highlighted box is the highest price for that week.

The future of prices is unknown, but in Scenarios 3 and 4 it is clear that company D is the highest as it is leading other companies in earlier weeks.

the prices are not random and ***could*** have a pattern as in Scenarios 3 and 4

A theory or rule name that can help me read more about

Answer (score 1):

The data is a red herring and the answer is very simple. Previous prices do not in any way tell you what future prices will be.

I suppose the most likely stock to have the highest price in the current week is slightly more likely to have the highest price in the future just because it has a head start.

If you are asking which one will have the best gain in the future, that is unanswerable without a crystal ball. That is why every stock quote and broker will have this disclaimer all over the place: "Past performance is not indicative of future results"

Comment: is there any name of a rule or theory that i can google to learn more about this topic?

Comment: You said "I suppose the most likely stock to have the highest price in the current week is slightly more likely to have the highest price in the future just because it has a head start." but what about the growing rate, if stock in the rise in previous weeks is more likely to keep rising and exceed a higher stock that is steady for weeks! am i right here?

Comment: What happened in the past has no bearing on what will happen in the future, at least not in a way that is in any way predictive. There are other schools of thought on this, but I wouldn't put much faith in them. The term you are looking for is "Technical Analysis"